# drop cap \IEEEPARstart: how to avoid rendering the characters as upper case?

Tags: ieeetran, drop-cap

I'm using the `\IEEEPARstart{}{}` command to "drop cap" the first letter of my paper. As explained in the [IEEEtran LATEX Class document](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) automatically :

> The other letters in the first word are rendered in upper case.

I don't want this as my first word is big and ugly. I want the rest of the characters to be rendered in lower case. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\IEEEPARstart{S}{upercalifragilisticexpialadocious}, 
if you say it loud enough, it's sounding quite atrocious

\bigskip

\IEEEPARstart{S}{\lowercase{upercalifragilisticexpialadocious}},
if you say it loud enough, it's sounding quite atrocious
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, you can even do this:

```
\IEEEPARstart{S}{}upercalifragilisticexpialadocious,
if you say it loud enough, it's sounding quite atrocious
```

Comment: I also added the `\textbf{}` to the second part so it is consistent with the first character.